# Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 128

Tags: wso2, signature, wso2-identity-server

Hi guys I am working with wso2 5.1.0 and I am trying to figure out where the error lays:

Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 128.

I checked in my code and the ExtendedMetadata I set as algorithm the rsa 256. I am using java 8 as runtime.

kind regards
Nikolaos

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it, the issue was that my cert was not imported in the default keystore wsacarbon used from SAML2 validator on the configuration. The solution there is to

- Either configure is to use your own jks which be default has your certs.
- Import your certs to the carbon default jks.
  In my case since is a dev environment and didn't want to spend time and energy I have imported my own certs in the default wsocabon.jks

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

if you use jdk 1.8 or 1.7 update it jdk 10+